# JSON.stringify inside Object.assign creates multiply properties

Tags: javascript, json

JSON stringify add additional properties to object when I use it with Object.assign.

Could you please explain me, why this happens and how to avoid it?

Example:
https://jsbin.com/mikokomibu/edit?js,console

```
//////////////////Example without JSON////////////////////
let object = {}
object = Object.assign({}, object, object[1]=2);
console.log(object)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Output:
[object Object] {
1: 2
}

//////////////////Example with JSON/////////////////////
let objectNew = {}
let first = JSON.stringify(1);
let second = JSON.stringify(2);
objectNew  = Object.assign({}, objectNew , objectNew[first]=second);
console.log(objectNew);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Output:
[object Object] {
0: "2",
1: "2"
}
```

Comment: please add what you really want. actually it makes no sense at all to stringify a number and use it as key for something. keys of objects are always converted to string.

Comment: Instead of numbers I want to use objects, I use it in breadth first search algorithm.  Numbers are only for example.

Comment: If you want to use objects for keys, you shouldn't use a plain object as container, but a `Map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Object.assign` encounters an iterable, it treats it as an array and assigns numeric properties to the target object:

```js
x = Object.assign({}, 'abc')
console.log(x)
```

Your first snippet is the same as this:

```
target = Object.assign({}, {1:2}, 2);
```

`assign` copies `object` to the target, and skips `2`, because it's a primitive.

The second snippet is like this:

```
target = Object.assign({}, {1:"2"}, "2");
```

here, `assign` copies `object` to the target, and processes `"2"`, which is an iterable, and equivalent to `{0:"2"}`, according to the above. So, the snippet turns into this

```
target = Object.assign({}, {1:"2"}, {0:"2"});
```

which explains your result.